# How to bulk transfer reports from one .org to another .org?

Tags: reporting, data, migration-tool, workbench, data-migration

My task is to upload all of the reports of an old .org to a completely new .org

I found that it is possible to retrieve reports via .xml-files from an old .org and upload it to a new org via workbench. Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
   <members>FOLDERA/REPORTA</members>
   <members>FOLDERB/REPORTB</members>
   <name>Report</name>
</types>
<version>43.0</version>
```

I've tested this way and it does work fine

BUT

the old .org contains thousands of reports and it would be quite tiresome to go through each folder at a time, customizing the .xml files each time.

Is there a way to mass download, transfer and upload all the reports and files at once, so that I have the exact same structure in the new and yet "clean" .org?

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Thank you already in advance!

UPDATE:

The suggestion from @Badbuxx, just retrieved an empty folder called "unpacked" cotaining the .xml file called "packaged" but unfortunately nothing more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package
xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
<version>43.0</version>
```

Comment: did you tried just to use  *<members>*</members>* ?

Comment: Thank you for your input @Badbaxx
I just did, but unfortunately the resulting .zip file is empty

Comment: Indeed. Just found this was documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm . Maybe that could help

Comment: @Badbaxx Does this mean there is no way to retrieve all the reports at once?

Comment: Unfortunatly seem like you have to retrieve the list of all your report with listMetadata() in your souce org and populaite package.xml with them. If you can use sfdx, you may try to retrieve / deploy with retrieve / deploy command

Comment: Thank you for your input @Badbaxx ... As you can tell I am quite inexperienced regarding this topic. Do you mind elaborating your idea further? The idea is to get a list overview of the account structure to use this list information in a big .xml transfer file to minimize the manual lookups?

Do you mind explaining how I get the list of the Report directories? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use VS Code and the Package.xml Generator extension to retrieve and deploy all reports and folders, see https://www.salesforceben.com/vscode-for-salesforce-admins-a-deeper-dive/